# Use openstacksdk created user, can not login

Tags: openstacksdk

My openstack version is ocata.
In my computer I installed the `openstacksdk (0.9.18)`, when I use it to create a openstack user like bellow:

```
# create openstack user
user_args = {
    "default_project_id":new_project.id,  # the project is created already, there I did not post here.
    "email":email,
    "is_enabled":True,
    "name":username,  
    "pasword":password,  
}

try:
    new_user = super_conn.conn.identity.create_user(**user_args)
except Exception as e:
    raise e

try:
    role_user = super_conn.conn.identity.find_role(OPENSTACK_ROLE_USER) # there I find the role(user)
    new_project.assign_role_to_user(super_conn.conn.session, new_user, role_user)  # assign to the new user
    new_project.validate_user_has_role(super_conn.conn.session, new_user, role_user)
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

I have debug the `username` and `password` in my code, my code is no mistake.

I created the new_user, and I also in openstack dashboard, checked the user and the user's project.
But I can not use the username and password to login the openstack dashboard.

Whether there is something wrong with it?

the error means the credentials invalid. So, I use openstack admin user to change the created user's password, then I can login yet.

Comment: How could you `change the user's password` ? Could you help me this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616030/how-openstacksdk-change-current-user-password , thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention anything about roles for the user.  Maybe the problem is lack of a role of any sort.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong and I was just looking at the identity api and I'm kind of surprised the password isn't supposed to be base64 encoded to allow various special characters, but I don't see anything about that.