# how openstacksdk change current user password

Tags: passwords, openstack, identity, openstacksdk

I found the **CLI** or **API request** methods and they work for me, like this:

```
# source /etc/kolla/admin-openrc.sh
# openstack user password set --password newpsw --original-password oripsw

Or

# source /etc/kolla/admin-openrc.sh
# curl -v -s -X POST $OS_AUTH_URL/auth/tokens?nocatalog \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"], \ 
 "password": {"user": {"domain": {"name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"}, \
 "name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"} } }, \
 "scope": { "project": { "domain": { "name": "'"$OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME"'" }, \
 "name":  "'"$OS_PROJECT_NAME"'" } } }}'
< HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
< Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2021 11:44:39 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 720
< X-Subject-Token: gAAAAABhbV4o9WvatToB4Z7dUhaNqyYqpwUt4T3wwOmnN2-YCioaSYZ-HpqdWNDvAq0pvnSe6qIuvoZXOIUjmxxUu03tWk2mp2TOJ_LTLECXOHqlQT22vqNvgJj_YTgOWbwHVlrrqbkcUWM4WDvbsD1HjM8xiEYidSNMzpw2LOHtO43cIN0nyvs
< Vary: X-Auth-Token
# export OS_TOKEN=gAAAAABhbV4o9WvatToB4Z7dUhaNqyYqpwUt4T3wwOmnN2-YCioaSYZ-HpqdWNDvAq0pvnSe6qIuvoZXOIUjmxxUu03tWk2mp2TOJ_LTLECXOHqlQT22vqNvgJj_YTgOWbwHVlrrqbkcUWM4WDvbsD1HjM8xiEYidSNMzpw2LOHtO43cIN0nyvs
# curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"user":{"password":"123","original_password":"aaa"}}' http://10.32.17.172:5000/v3/users/e1c5cc75489f4e0cbb05c39d03b46097/password
```

The **`Change password for user`** method at the last of **API request** [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=update-user-detail,change-password-for-user-detail#users).

But I need to achieve that by using **[openstacksdk](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/identity_v3.html#user-operations)** in our project, I found the last method in the `openstacksdk` documentation -- `update_user(user, **attrs)`, it seems the most like I look for. Unfortunately, the [openstack.identity.v3.user instance](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/resources/identity/v3/user.html#openstack.identity.v3.user.User) doesn't have the `original_password`, and my code can't work:

```
import openstack

conn = openstack.connect(
    region_name = 'RegionOne',
    auth_url = 'http://10.32.17.172:35357/v3',
    domain_name = 'Default',
    project_name = 'admin',
    username = 'admin',
    password = '123'
)

user_args = {
    "name":"admin",
    "pasword":'aaa',  # new password
    "password_expires_at":None, 
    "links":{u'self': u'http://10.32.17.172:5000/v3/users/e1c5cc75489f4e0cbb05c39d03b46097'},
    "enabled":True, 
    "domain_id":"default",
    "original_password": "123",
}

conn.identity.update_user(user_args)
```

How could I implement change current user passord by `openstacksdk`? Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by this:

```
import openstack
conn = openstack.connect(
    ...
)
user_args = {
    "id":"e1c5cc75489f4e0cbb05c39d03b46097"
}
user = conn.identity.get_user(user_args)
user.description = "test_update_psw"
user.password="123456"
conn.identity.update_user(user)
```

Update the user's info should use the `user` object instead of the `dictionary` like the question's code.

Shame of my bad program language skill and lack of API documentation knowledge.

[And thank you very very much for one people who called tanjin](https://storyboard.openstack.org/#!/story/2009306#comment-180653).