# How To Fetch Projec quotas using OpenstackSDK?

Tags: python, openstack, openstacksdk

I am looking for a small code to **fetch all my projects quotas limits**. From `openstacksdk` dev repository i can see there is connection called `compute.v2.limits`, but using that i m getting blank output like below.

```
import openstack
import openstack.compute.v2.limits
import os
import datetime

################## getting limits ##########################
ip='10.6.X.X'
auth_url_domain="https://10.6.X.X:13000/v3"
conn = openstack.connect(auth_url=auth_url_domain, project_name="admin", username="admin", domain_name="default",password="XXXXXX", cacert="/root/app/cacrt/cacrt/ca.crt10.6.X.X.pem")
data=openstack.compute.v2.limits.AbsoluteLimits(session=conn)
print(data.to_dict())
```

Output i m getting ( key is ok but values are none . I want values should be as per values set for all projects):

```
{'server_groups': None, 'keypairs': None, 'total_ram_used': None,
 'total_cores': None, 'instances_used': None, 'total_cores_used': None,
 'instances': None, 'id': None, 'security_groups': None,
 'total_ram': None, 'floating_ips': None, 'location': None,
 'personality_size': None, 'server_groups_used': None,
 'personality': None, 'security_group_rules': None,
 'name': None, 'server_group_members': None, 'floating_ips_used': None,
 'image_meta': None, 'server_meta': None, 'security_groups_used': None}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the project quota only by **[openstack.connection](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html#openstack.connection.Connection.get_compute_quotas)**, like this:

```
conn = openstack.connect(auth_url=auth_url_domain...)
quotas = conn.get_compute_quotas(project_name_or_id)
```

And there is more other common methods, you could check it while you need.

> I want values should be as per values set for all projects

If you want to get all projects quotas, you should create the consistent `connection` because of the connection bind the project as the parameter of `openstack.connect` method. But if you are the `admin` role, you could get all projects info.

Comment: HI @VictorLee . Thanks for the suggestion . So after your suggestion to fetch all projects quota my code should be like below
` ################## getting limits ##########################
ip='10.6.X.X'
auth_url_domain="https://10.6.X.X:13000/v3"
conn = openstack.connect(auth_url=auth_url_domain, project_name="admin", username="admin", domain_name="default",password="XXXXXX", cacert="/root/app/cacrt/cacrt/ca.crt10.6.X.X.pem")
quotas=conn.get_compute_quotas()
print(quotas.to_dict())`

Comment: @KASHIFIQBAL Welcome, it's that works by your code above? Maybe this method `get_compute_quotas() ` should get one required positional argument `name_or_id`. If this answer could solve your question, you could accept it or vote it up. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks @VictorLee . I m able to achieve my target . Thanks for your quick support .
 from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
ram, cores, instances --> (51200, 20, 10)
Munch({u'per_volume_gigabytes': -1, u'snapshots_tripleo-ceph': -1, u'groups': 10, u'gigabytes_tripleo-ceph': -1, u'gigabytes': 1000, u'backup_gigabytes': 1000, u'snapshots': 10, u'volumes_tripleo-ceph': -1, u'volumes': 10, u'backups': 10, u'id': u'6258ed8df4d34d0b817ab102e66c8d4a'})

Comment: @KASHIFIQBAL welcome, learn from each other, I also find some method to change the admin's password by `openstacksdk`, but I can't figure out until now, do you have some suggest ? Thanks advance. Check it from below link if you have free time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616030/how-openstacksdk-change-current-user-password

Comment: No @VictorLee i m new to it . Let me explore in my lab will let you know . if i found something.